# Pentaho CCC Bar chart : displaying a threshold

Tags: pentaho

I have a bar chart displaying a monthly ratio (e.g. amount of sales in a country ) : I have the month on horizontal axis and the height of each bar is the amount.

Let's assume that the boss sayed 'the monthly amount of sales must be at least 10000€' : I would like to draw an horizontal line with y-coordinate = 10000

How can I do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution : I have had a plot2 with the value of 10000 => that draws a circle ; then, in the post execution, I wrote some javascript in order to replace the circle by a line